# Accessing a pandas string column characters based on indices in a series or array

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe column (series) containing indices to a single character of interest inside the string elements of another column. Is there a way for me to access these characters of interest based on the index column in a vectorized manner, similar to the dataframe['name'].str.* functions? *[edit: see comment below]* If not (or regardless, really), what would you say is the preferred approach here?

*[Edit: this assumption was wrong, as pointed out by jpp, but I'm leaving it here for traceability]*

I'm trying to avoid being unnecessarily verbose, such as applying a translation function using `map` or having to construct a separate indexing recipe (like a dictionary containing the indices) in order to do something like

```
myDataFrame['myDesiredResult'] = 
    myDataFrame['myStrCol'].apply(myCharacterExtractionFunction, myIndexingRecipe)
```

I'd prefer sticking to numpy and pandas and not mix in more modules if at all possible.

Illustration of what the data might look like:

```
     myStrCol  myIndices  myDesiredResult
0    ABC       1          B
1    DEF       0          D
2    GHI       2          I
```

Also, and maybe useful in order to get an understanding of how the numpy array is actually behaving inside the pandas wrapper, it would be great if someone could explain if it makes a difference to have a separate numpy array containing the indices, like this:

```
import pandas
import numpy

myPandasStringSeries = pandas.Series(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'])
myPandasStringSeries
    0    ABC
    1    DEF
    2    GHI

myNumpyIndexArray = numpy.array([1, 0, 2])
myNumpyIndexArray
    array([1, 0, 2])
```

It seems to me that what I want is very similar to [this suggestion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8748) relating to substrings but there doesn't seem to be a solution there yet. Apart from that, all I have found relates to the Series.str methods which operate using the *same parameter* for all elements of the Series like so:

```
myDataFrame['newColumn'] = myDataFrame['oldColumn'].str.split('_').str.get(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to access these characters of interest based on
>   the index column in a vectorized manner, similar to the
>   `dataframe['name'].str.*` functions?

There is a misunderstanding here. Despite the documentation, [`pd.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) methods are **not** vectorised in the conventional sense. They operate in a high-level loop and often reflect the functionality in Python's built-in `str` methods.

In fact, `pd.Series.str` methods generally **underperform** simple list comprehensions when manipulating strings stored in Pandas dataframes. The convenient syntax should not be taken as a sign the underlying implementation is vectorised. This is often the case for series with dtype `object`.

One approach is to use a list comprehension:

```
df['myDesiredResult'] = [i[k] for i, k in zip(df['myStrCol'], df['myIndices'])]
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Works like a charm. (I left my misunderstanding in there with a reference to your correction, in order to keep the connection to your full answer.)